# Outlook 2016, The "Select Members" dialog for adding members to a Contact Group does not show recently added contacts

Tags: contacts, microsoft-outlook-2016

With Outlook 2016 (Office 360 subscription) when I attempt to add members to a new (or existing) Contact Group, the `Select Members` dialog box only shows contacts added in the distant past. Recently added contacts do not show up - although recently added Contact Groups are present.

Any idea of how to force Outlook to refresh the dialog's list of contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the address book in Outlook:

1. Open Send/Receive ribbon tab.
2. Click the "Send/Receive Groups" button and select the "Download Address Book".
3. *Uncheck* the "Download changes ..." option to force the full AB download and click OK.